Google Chat API Permission Issues
I created a google chatbot that is connected to an AI model using cloud run function. I made it to send async messages because the model tends to work for longer than 30 seconds.
I did it with this code:
def send_asynchronous_chat_message(thread_id, body, message_id=None):
    space_id = thread_id.split(",")[1]
    logging.info("space id %s" % space_id)
    space_name = f"spaces/{space_id}"

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    chat = build('chat', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # update content of an existing message
    if message_id:
        response_obj = chat.spaces().messages().update(
            name=message_id,
            updateMask='text',
            body=body
        ).execute()

    # create a new message
    else:
        response_obj = chat.spaces().messages().create(
            parent=space_name,
            body=body
        ).execute()

    return response_obj.get("name")

It works fine when I use it with a Chat API that is in the same project as the Cloud Run Function but when I try to add the trigger URL to a Chat API that is in another organisation/project I get this error when I send a message.
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/XXXXXXXXXX/messages?alt=json returned "This Chat app is not a member of this space.". Details: "This Chat app is not a member of this space.">
The Chat API is enabled on the project.
Is there a solution for this? Wihtout putting my app on the marketplace.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rust?Swift? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

You need a service account with domain-wide delegation enabled.
To enable domain-wide delegation for a service account in Google Workspace, you can:
Create a service account in the Google Cloud console
Copy the service account's Client ID from the Google Cloud console
Sign in to the Google Admin console as a super administrator
Go to Menu > Security > Access and data control > API controls
Select Manage Domain Wide Delegation
Click Add new
Enter the service account's Client ID
Enter a comma-delimited list of OAuth Scopes in the OAuth Scopes field
Click Authorize
Domain-wide delegation allows a service account to impersonate any user in a Cloud Identity or Workspace account. This gives the service account access to the user's Google Workspace data, bypassing the user's consent.

Thank you, but it is a bit cloudy for me. Do I have to add the client id from the service account of the project where the cloud function is to the api control of the project where the chat api is?

sure, you should apply these changes on destination.

attention to:  The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error response status code and more detail in error
